# How to remove lines from a binary image file in java?

Tags: java

I have this jpeg file which has these 4 lines at the top I want removed.

```
--Boundary+F8FFFA18070580D7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data";`filename="MySurveyImage0.jpg"
Content-Type: image/JPEG
ˇÿˇ‡JFIFHHˇ·XExifMM*ái&††¿†
êˇÌ8Photoshop 3.08BIM8BIM%‘åŸè≤ÈÄ
```

I tried reading the input stream as lines, removing the first 4 lines and rewriting to the file. Since IOUtils.readLines reads the file as text the image file gets corrupted.

```
List<String> strings = IOUtils.readLines(objectContent);
strings.subList(3, strings.size()
```

I think I need to use proper encoding. How do I read the binary, remove the first 4 lines and rewrite the file without corrupting the content?

Comment: why do you think binary will read into Strings?

Comment: Did you do any research? Use a byte-oriented approach with `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` to avoid encoding issues altogether.  Then examine the input at the start looking for the line delimiters. You'll have to know if they're `\n` or `\r\n`.  Also, that looks like only 3 lines to remove, not 4.  You most definitely ***DO NOT*** want to use anything character/string oriented, that will corrupt the file.

Comment: This looks like a attachment in a e-mail for instance. Don't you have a way to extract the content?

Answer (score -1):

Consider reading image as a binary image file and then extract/modify exif information.

Apache Commons Imaging provides easy api for that.
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/index.html

Comment: How does the question relate to the exif-information in any way?